# Installed cPanel -amp- WHM- AMI on AWS - Can't Login to WHM or cPanel

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-ec2, cpanel, whm

I installed the cPanel & WHM: The Hosting Platform of Choice AMI on AWS last night on a ec2 instance.

It seems to have set it all up and I can get to the login pages of cPanel and WHM but can not log in.

I used the 1-click install and never entered, or was given a user/password combination.

Where can I find or set this information?

I can login through ssh from the aws portal and there is definitely a password set. I tried using

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

to reset it but failed to login because I did not have a password. It is not blank.

I am not very familiar with doing things through SSH so please be specific on how to fix this if I need to do it through SSH.

Thank you so much for your help.

Any advice or suggestions about AWS is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon doesn't allow you to connect through the dashboard as root, you have to login as the user type. In this case, ec2-user. Logged in as this user doesn't allow you use the "passwd" command without the old password. However, you can authenticate as root, then use the passwd command to change the password without having to know the old one/default install. Here's how.

1. Log into SSH in as the ec2-user.
2. Run "sudo -i" to authenticate as root.
3. Once you're "root", you can reset the root password using "passwd".
4. Then login to WHM.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the port/firewall setting. Please enable all cPanel require ports for your AWS and try to login cPanel/WHM.

Here are the all port lists which you need to enable for your server.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7536715#HowtoConfigureYourFirewallforcPanel&WHM%27sServices-Ports

Comment: Thanks for the port info, that will be helpful. However, I can get to the login pages fine. It just wants a login and password which I never received nor set up. I clicked the 1-click setup. It says it's ready just log in, but I do not know the login credentials.

Comment: Try to use your root password of your server which you are using for SSH login.

Comment: I am not using pw to login. AWS uses key pairs to login to SSH. So I don't even have a basic login to try.

Comment: Okay, Login your server with key and reset your root password with passwd command and then try to login  your WHM with that password

Comment: So for AWS it will not let me login as root, I have to login as ec2-user but have sudo access. When trying to use the passwd command it still asks for the current password. If I enter blank or any other password for AWS I might have I get this error: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
I have a ticket into cPanel to see if they can help. About to just give up and set up servers elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed some step before

```
wget -N http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/latest
```

I've got the same issue and ended with deleting the instance and staring over.
The only setup guide that worked for me without any issues: https://5best.cloud/build-cpanel-cloud-hosting-amazon-aws-1/